# Приоритеты и ассоциативность операторов javascript

Tags: javascript, математика

Почему код работает так:

```js
var a = 15, b = 10, c;
c = a % (a = b);
console.log(c);
// второй случай

a = a++ + a;
console.log(a);
```

В первом случае я рассуждал так: сначала выполниться код в скобках

`(a=b) и a будет равно 10`

Потом в левой части выражения, a поменяет свое значение на десять, а так как скобки справа дадут нам тоже ***10***.

`10 % 10 = 0`

Но почему то это не так?

Значит значения переменных вычисляются до работы с операторами? Но почему во втором случае это не так?

Comment: что именно Вас смущает?

Comment: В таблице написано % слева-направо. Т.е. сначала вычисляется левая часть, заносится в стек вычислений, потом правая (то что в скобках).

Answer (score 0):

Код доказывающий что во втором примере вторая переменная выражения меняется:

```js
var a = 5, b = 5;
a = a++ + b;
console.log(a)
```

Порядок исполнения тут такой: сначала переменная `a` возвращает значение 5, а потом меняет свое на 6. После, `b+5=10` и в переменную `a` записываеться значение 10.

Answer (score 0):

*Значит значения переменных вычисляются до работы с операторами? Но почему во втором случае это не так?*

Просто переменная **a** у Вас глобальная и уже оказалась переопределена выше (в первом случае). Соответственно, во втором случае используется её новое значение.

Answer (score 0):

Все очень предельно понятно, если знать [приоритеты операторов и ассоциативность](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence).

```
c = a % (a = b);
```

В данном случае оператор `( ... )` имеет приоритет - `20`, `... % ...` - `14`, а `… = …` - `3`.
А теперь по порядку:

1. (a = b): вы вынесли в отдельный блок, что `a = b` надо рассматривать как одно целое, но оператор `=` не выполнен, следующий оператор по приоритету `%`
2. При выполнении оператора `%` у вас есть переменная `a=15`, и `(a = b)`, но оператор `=` все еще не выполнен, то есть `a != 10`, как вы этого ожидаете.
3. Но тем не менее надо выбрать что-то из `(a = b)` для поиска остатка от деления, если внимательно посмотрите таблицу, то оператор `=` имеет ассоциативность справа на лева, то есть `(a = b)` вернут значение `b`, которое равно `10`.
4. Только потом будут выполняться операторы `=`, то есть `a` станет равно `b`.
5. А `c` станет равно `15%10 = 5`.
6. `a = a++ + a` вернут `21`, потому что `а` в пункте `4` все таки приняло значение `b`, которое равно `10`: `10++ + 11 = 21`

Comment: В пункте 6 у Вас не совсем корректно: там 10++ + 11, т.е. второй операнд - это новое значение 'a' после инкрементации. Это важно, потому что если было бы ++а + а, результат оказался бы 22, а если бы a++ + b, то 20.

Comment: @humster_spb точно, спасибо.